# How to find pixel boundaries of a QGraphicsPixmapItem in a QGraphicsScene

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a png that is read into my python program as a QGraphicsPixmapItem. This QGraphicsPixmapItem is then added to a QGraphicsScene for display. Within the display, users can zoom in and pan through the image. This works as intended.

My question is this: How can I determine what **PNG pixel values** are at the corners of the QGraphicsScene after being zoomed and panned?

Is there a built-in PyQt method for this?

My current code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog


class PhotoViewer(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QPoint)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(PhotoViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self._zoom = 0
        self._empty = True
        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._photo = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self._scene.addItem(self._photo)
        self.setScene(self._scene)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(30, 30, 30)))
        self.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)

    def hasPhoto(self):
        return not self._empty

    def fitInView(self, scale=True):
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(self._photo.pixmap().rect())

        if not rect.isNull():
            self.setSceneRect(rect)

            if self.hasPhoto():
                unity = self.transform().mapRect(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
                self.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())

                viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
                scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)

                factor = min(viewrect.width()  / scenerect.width(),
                             viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
                self.scale(factor, factor)

            self._zoom = 0

    def setPhoto(self, pixmap=None):
        self._zoom = 0

        if pixmap and not pixmap.isNull():
            self._empty = False
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(pixmap)
        else:
            self._empty = True
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap())

        self.fitInView()

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if self.hasPhoto():
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                factor = 1.25
                self._zoom += 1
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self._zoom -= 1

            if self._zoom > 0:
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            elif self._zoom == 0:
                self.fitInView()
            else:
                self._zoom = 0

    def toggleDragMode(self):
        if self.dragMode() == QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag:
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
        elif not self._photo.pixmap().isNull():
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self._photo.isUnderMouse():
            self.photoClicked.emit(self.mapToScene(event.pos()).toPoint())

        super(PhotoViewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.viewer = PhotoViewer(self)

        # 'Load image' button
        self.btnLoad = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.btnLoad.setText('Load image')
        self.btnLoad.clicked.connect(self.loadImage)

        # Button to change from drag/pan to getting pixel info
        self.btnPixInfo = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.btnPixInfo.setText('Enter pixel info mode')
        self.btnPixInfo.clicked.connect(self.pixInfo)
        self.editPixInfo = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.editPixInfo.setReadOnly(True)
        self.viewer.photoClicked.connect(self.photoClicked)

        # Arrange layout
        VBlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        VBlayout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        HBlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        HBlayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnLoad)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnPixInfo)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.editPixInfo)
        VBlayout.addLayout(HBlayout)

    def loadImage(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.png)", options=options)

        if fileName:
            self.viewer.setPhoto(QtGui.QPixmap(fileName))

    def pixInfo(self):
        self.viewer.toggleDragMode()

    def photoClicked(self, pos):
        if self.viewer.dragMode()  == QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.NoDrag:
            self.editPixInfo.setText('%d, %d' % (pos.x(), pos.y()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the coordinates of the viewport(), map it in the QGraphicsScene and then map it in the QGraphicsPixmapItem:

```
rect_scene = self.mapToScene(self.viewport().rect())
rect_item = self._photo.mapFromScene(rect_scene).boundingRect().toRect()
print("Coordinates:\n============")
print("top-left:", rect_item.topLeft())
print("top-right:", rect_item.topRight())
print("bottom-left:", rect_item.bottomLeft())
print("bottom-right:", rect_item.bottomRight())
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add

```
print(self.mapToScene(0, 0))
print(self.mapToScene(self.viewport().rect().width(), self.viewport().rect().height()))
```

to the wheelEvent() method to determine the approximate PNG pixel boundaries, but this only updates if the user zooms in. Any ideas on how to allow it to update when the image has been panned as well?

Comment: Please, don't create an answer to add another question, edit your question instead and remove this answer.